# Template literals & string interpolation as a javascript method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, string-interpolation, template-literals

So I currently have a weatherAPI that will return an icon code that is a string and starts with a number `02d`,`01d`,`01n`,`04d`, etc. Now, what I want to do is pull in a react svg component dynamically depending on what the icon code is. Let me explain how I am trying to do it and then you can see if there is a better way to handle this.

To make things simple, I am passing down the response from the API down to a `dumb component`. I then created a folder `weatherIcons`, which contains all my svg components:

```
src
|_components
  |_dashboard
  | |_DumbComponent.js
  |_weatherIcons
    |_02d.js
    |_01d.js
    |_01n.js
    |_index.js
```

In my `DumbComponent.js` I am requiring all my svg components through the index file located under `weatherIcons` folder like so: `import * as Icon from '../common/svg/weatherIcons';`

The `index.js` file inside of `weatherIcons` folder will serve up each component like:

```
export {default as 01d} from './01d';
export {default as 02d} from './02d';
export {default as 01n} from './01n';
```

This allows me then to call these files as methods inside my `DumbComponent.js` like: `Icon.01d()`. This will then return the svg component in `src/components/weatherIcons/01d.js'. As you know though, this WON'T actually return that file, because a method cannot start with an integer and thus my dilemma. Nor can I give a name of`01d`,`02d`,`01n`like I did in my`weatherIcons/index.js` file.

My thought process was to give them a name spacing that starts with a character:

```
export {default as code01d} from './01d';
export {default as code02d} from './02d';
export {default as code01n} from './01n';
```

Then try and interpolate the code from the api response as a function. `Icon.code${apiRESPONSE}()`. Any ideas on how this can be done or any other work around for this current situation.

ps. I have looked into `react-svg` and other svg importers and prefer to not take the approach of importing the svg's as html and through a path.

Comment: If you want to interpolate, try this: `Icon['code' + apiRESPONSE]()`. You can use ES6 string interpolations if you want.

Comment: IDK why but this does not work for me. I tried `Icon['code' + '01d']()`. This did work for me. So I know I have appropriately made an instance of my `weatherIcons` folder and setup my `index.js` the right way. However, when I attempt to do `Icon['code' + apiRESPONSE]()`, I get: `Icon.code${apiRESPONSE} is not a function(...)` =(

Comment: @Nappstir That's a weird error message, suggesting that `apiRESPONSE` is the string `"${apiRESPONSE}"`. Are you sure that your code is `Icon['code' + apiRESPONSE]`? If yes, please log the value of `apiRESPONSE` before the concatenation.

Comment: @Nappstir It sounds as if you tried to use template strings but chose the quote or apostrophe instead of the backtick: `Icon['code${apiRESPONSE}']`?. ```Icon[`code${apiRESPONSE}`]``` should work.

Comment: I figured out what the issue is. When the component first gets rendered, the data has yet to come through. So `apiRESPONSE` is getting set to an empty string. It does eventually get set to the appropriate `iconCode`, however it does not re-run the block of code ``Icon[`code${apiRESPONSE}`]()``